# how can I create an object from a python class and use it in a Java program written under spark's API

Tags: java, python, apache-spark

I have a program written in Java. This program read data from the database, Analyze each record and write the result into the database again. 
I am trying to rewrite my code with Spark's API in Java, but some parts of analyzing on each record is being done by a Python code. my question is how can I call my python object in Java code written under Java Spark's API? by that I mean, create an object from python class only once in Java for analyzing database records an keep it alive in order to avoid initializing python object for every record under Java Spark's API?
Thanks

Comment: Please bring some example and narrow down your question.

Comment: I need somehow pass Java output code (Java RDD) to Python code or create an object from my Python class in my Java code to do some analyze on my database records

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

1. Migrate Python code to Java and use it
2. Invoke the python executable using system() function
3. To create corresponding java object of python object, you can depend on serialization.

Comment: by Invoking python code how can I create an object from python class? I mean I need create a link between Java and Python code under Java Spark's API

Comment: @A.Mani added  third option

Comment: could you please explain a little more about the third option since I am not familiar with  serialization? Thanks a million